# Why it is important to cache loaded XslCompiledTransform instances

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

Especially for server applications, whether to cache an XslCompiledTransform instance if the same stylesheet is likely to be executed again.Why it is important to cache loaded XslCompiledTransform instances?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the cost of compiling a stylesheet is high compared with the cost of executing it, and you don't want to incur this cost on each transformation if you can avoid it.